# Controller returns file but download does not start

Tags: .net, excel, ajax, csv, model-view-controller

So i've got this form that I submit to a controller

```
          asp-controller="DataMigration"
          data-ajax="true"
          data-ajax-method="GET"
          id="exportForm">

        <div class="importStep">
            <span class="importStepTitle">@ImportExport_Products.selectClassExport</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input id="exportType" name="exportType" type="hidden" value="0" />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => selectedClassId, new SelectList(Model.importModel.Classes, "Key", "Value"), "---", new
            {
                id = "classesDropdownExport",
                @class = "importStepCategorySelect r3 select2-lib"
            })

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => languageId, new SelectList(Model.languages, "Id", "LanguageName"), new
            {
               id = "languagesDropDownExport",
               @class = "importLanguageSelect r3 select2-lib"
            })
            <div class="help-icon-container">
                <span title="@ImportExport_Products.SelectLanguageForExport" class="helpIcon"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="submitExportBtn" class="btn btn-primary button btn-file r3 disabled">
            @GlobalResource.ExportToExcel
        </button>
    </form>
```

The controller returns a file

```
        {
            if (selectedClassId <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(selectedClassId));
            }

            if(languageId <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(languageId));
            }

            const string exportTypeName = "GoodTagProperties";
            Class catalogClass = await Class.GetAsync(this._dataAccessLayerAdapter, _memoryCache, selectedClassId, languageId, true);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(catalogClass.UniqueName))
            {
                return BadRequest("Incorrect class id");
            }

            IList<Property> properties = await GetAndInitializePropertiesForTable(selectedClassId, languageId);
            DataTable dataTable = await PrepareTable(allGoods, languageId, catalogClass, properties);

            return exportType == ExportType.Csv
                ? File(CSVHelper.ExportDataTableToCsvByteArray(dataTable), ExportHelper.CsvMimeType, ExportHelper.GetFileName(exportTypeName, selectedClassId.ToString()))
                : File(ExportHelper.GetXlsDocumentInBytes(dataTable), ExportHelper.ExcelMimeType, ExportHelper.GetFileName(exportTypeName, selectedClassId.ToString(), ExportHelper.ExcelFileExtension));
        }
```

but the download does not start unless I go to the network tab and open the response in a new tab. How do I make it to be automatically downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what I found was that this problem is occured because I've used ajax. Simply changing:

```
   asp-controller="DataMigration"
   data-ajax="true"
   data-ajax-method="GET"
   id="exportForm">
```

To:

```
    asp-action="GetGoodTagProperties"
    asp-controller="DataMigration"
    method="get"
    id="exportForm">
```

Did the trick